# How to explain the coefficients in the marginal effects of Logit regression?

Tags: econometrics, reference-request

I am asked to interpret the coefficients of the specification showed the marginal effects of [Logit regression](https://quantifyinghealth.com/interpret-logistic-regression-coefficients/).

I am wondering if there is any reference for this work. I am finding [a link that is quite useful in interpreting the coefficients in the Logit model](https://quantifyinghealth.com/interpret-logistic-regression-coefficients/) but not sure if it is different from the "marginal effects of Logit regression".

Answer (score 3):

Coefficients from logit have essentially no practical interpretation.

$$Pr(y = 1 |X) = \frac{e^{\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{1i}+...+\beta_k x_{ki}}}{1+e^{\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{1i}+...+\beta_k x_{ki}}}$$

It's really not obvious how to interpret $\beta_j$ for any $j$.

The marginal effect is: $$\frac{\partial Pr(y=1|X)}{\partial Xj}= \beta_j \frac{e^{\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{1i}+...+\beta_k x_{ki}}}{(1+e^{\beta_0 +\beta_1 x_{1i}+...+\beta_k x_{ki}})^2} $$

The marginal effect is the derivative of $Y$ with respect to $X$, this is easier to interpret. Marginal effects can be evaluated (1) for a specific individual, plugging that individual's X values, (2) for the mean individual, plugging in the average of X for all individuals, or (3) for all individuals, then averaged.

The third option is "average marginal effects", and typically considered "best".

My slides on this are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U4cdqA-22O1k4CtrF9o7kt85681Cn6eI/view). Logit starts around slide 20 and I talk about marginal effects around slide 30.

I'm not sure if I answered your question, so feel free to follow up.